# How to copy array while removing last character and obtain result as double

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table of data in format "numberletter" i.e. 1X, 2.5X, -5X etc. What I am trying to do is to grab the data, remove last character from each cell(there is always only one letter at the end of the value), multiply the result by a constant value and paste it back to a different cells.

Right now, with code below, I am able to get values from first table copied to the second table with last letter removed but the result is string instead of number.

```vb
Dim vData
Dim n As Long
Dim r As Long
    vData = Range("E6:J500").Value
    For n = 1 To UBound(vData, 1)
    For r = 1 To 6
        If Len(vData(n, r)) <> 0 Then vData(n, r) = Left$(vData(n, r), Len(vData(n, r)) - 1)
    Next r
    Next n
    Range("R6:W500").Value = vData
```

I've tried to add function below, but I am not able to make it work with my previous code due to mismatch error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Function ConvertArray(arrStr() As String) As Double()
    Dim strS As String
    Dim intL As Integer
    Dim intU As Integer
    Dim intCounter As Integer
    Dim intLen As Integer
    Dim arrDbl() As Double
    intL = LBound(arrStr)
    intU = UBound(arrStr)
    ReDim arrDbl(intL To intU)
    intCounter = intL
    Do While intCounter <= UBound(arrDbl)
        arrDbl(intCounter) = CDbl(arrStr(intCounter))
        intCounter = intCounter + 1
    Loop

    ConvertArray = arrDbl

End Function
```

Comment: What is the constant value to multiply with?

Comment: I define the constant as:
Dim A As Double
A = 10
And then I guess I would have to add another loop multiplying all cells by A.

Comment: Simply `... = Val(Left$(vData(n, r), Len(vData(n, r))) * A`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be another better way, but I find `.Evaluate` an interesting option which in this case could work for you.:

```
Sub Test()

Dim cnst As Long: cnst = 10
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change accordingly
    .Range("R6:W500") = .Evaluate("IFERROR(IF(ROW(1:500),LEFT(E6:J500,IF(ROW(1:500),LEN(E6:J500)-1)),"""")*" & cnst & ","""")")
End With

End Sub
```

---

Or with a little bit more flexibility with variable ranges:

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 as range, cnst As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change accordingly
    Set rng1 = .Range("E6:J500")
    Set rng2 = .Range("R6:W500")
    cnst = 10
    rng2.Value = .Evaluate("IFERROR(IF(ROW(1:500),LEFT(" & rng1.Address & ",IF(ROW(1:500),LEN(" & rng1.Address & ")-1)),"""")*" & cnst & ","""")")
End With

End Sub
```

The `IFFERROR` is in there because you seem to check your range for length above 0 too.

---

[image]

[Here](https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/06/19/avoid-loop-for-range-calculations-evaluate/) you can find why I used `ROW(1:500)` in `.Evaluate`:).

Comment: Very Nice!  `rng2.Value = .Evaluate("IFERROR(IF(ROW(1:" & rng1.Rows.Count & "),LEFT(" & rng1.Address & ",IF(ROW(1:" & rng1.Rows.Count & "),LEN(" & rng1.Address & ")-1)),"""")*" & cnst & ","""")")` is more flexible but I would have never thought of this solution in the first place!

Comment: @TinMan, for sure, that's even better. :)

Answer (score 1):

The Type Mismatch error is caused because `Range.Value` returns a variant array not a string array.  It is also a 2D Array.

`Val()` can be used by itself to return the string value as long as the left part of the string contains the value.

```
Function ConvertArray(arrStr() As Variant, Multiplier As Double) As Double()
    Dim results() As Double
    ReDim results(1 To UBound(arrStr), 1 To UBound(arrStr, 2))

    Dim r As Long, c As Long

    For r = 1 To UBound(arrStr)
        For c = 1 To UBound(arrStr, 2)
            results(r, c) = Val(arrStr(r, c)) * Multiplier
        Next
    Next

    ConvertArray = results
End Function

Sub Test()
    Dim data() As Variant
    data = Range("E6:J500").Value

    Range("R6:W500").Value = ConvertArray(data, 10)
End Sub

Sub Prep()
    Range("E6:J500").Formula = "=RandBetween(1,1000)&""X"""
    Range("E6:J500").Value = Range("E6:J500").Value
End Sub
```

[image: Results Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You need the VBA `Val(String)` function.  This will take the numerics from your string **until** it finds a letter.  It does a bit more than that as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/val-function?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1009055)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue).
So you could replace your:

```
For r = 1 To 6
    If Len(vData(n, r)) <> 0 Then vData(n, r) = Left$(vData(n, r), Len(vData(n, r)) - 1)
Next r
```

With:

```
For r = 1 To 6
    vData(n, r) = Val(vData(n, r)
Next r
```